# PHP: replace hypen with space character

Tags: php

I have string

> > "*A----*B----".

I want to replace all hypen ('-') characters  by space character (' '). I used str_replace as

> > str_replace('-', ' ', "*A-----*B-----").

The result should be

> > "*A<5 spaces>*B<5 spaces>"

but instead it gives me

> > "*A *B "

Why space characters are not preserved? I need to preserve space characters in the string.

[Interestingly, while posting this question, even i cant type a tring with empty spaces :) ]

Comment: HMTL ignores consecutive spaces and display it as one (although in the code itself it's still technically 5 space characters). Use `&nbsp;` instead

Comment: Is this for output in html?

Comment: `Interestingly, while posting this question, even i cant type a tring with empty spaces :) ` Answer to your question and solution to your above SO issue is same :) i.e. Multiple spaces are displayed as a single space by web browsers. To display it right use `<pre>` tag in HTML and use code tag in SO.

Comment: @Krishtian82, i want to save this string in file.

Comment: When you want to see the actual output from PHP when you are building web-pages, always look at the page source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's because you're displaying your string in an HTML page, which ignores multiple white spaces. If you want to see them, try echoing between `<pre>` tags:

```
echo "<pre>" . $yourstring . "</pre>";
```

or using `&nbsp;`:

```
str_replace('-', '&nbsp;', "*A-----*B-----");
```

Answer (score 3):

Multiple spaces are displayed as single spaces in all browsers.

To stop this behaviour, you can either use `&nbsp;` (Non Breaking SPace) or `white-space: pre` CSS on the containing element.

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
str_replace('–', '&nbsp;', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `str_replace('–', '&nbsp;', $str);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All, you all are right. Actually i was preparing some EDI document and before creating a file i dumped output to browser to check its validity. I saw source of html and yes it has 5 spaces where required.

Answer (score 0):

HTML ignores multiple spaces after a character, to add multiple spaces in HTML use a non breaking space char `&nbsp;`

This should replace `-` with non breaking space char and solve the problem

```
str_replace('–', '&nbsp;', $str);
```